# C - Unusual Result When Intertwining Two Char Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, buffer, concatenation

I'm working on a project that requires two strings to be "intertwined" together so that they alternate each character. 
Example: "Apple" and "BEAR" would become "ABpEpAlRe"

This is my current function:

```
void printMessage(char name[], char num[])
{
    char eticket[(sizeof(name)/sizeof(char))+((sizeof(num))/sizeof(char))] = ""; //make array with enough space for both strings
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(eticket)/sizeof(char));i++)
    {
        char tmp[1] ={name[i]}; // i have to change the char name[i] and num[i] to its own char array so i can use it in strcat
        char tmp2[1] ={num[i]};
        if(i<(sizeof(name)/sizeof(char))-1) //if name string is finished, don't concatenate
        {
            strcpy(eticket,strcat(eticket, tmp));
        }
        if(i<(sizeof(num)/sizeof(char))-1) //if num string is finished, don't concatenate
        {
            strcpy(eticket,strcat(eticket, tmp2));
        }
    }

    printf("Your name is %s and your flight number is %s.\nYour e-ticket is: %s.\n\n", name, num, eticket);
}
```

Where eticket is the final string.

The result:

```
Your name is Connor and your flight number is MIA1050.
Your e-ticket is: CMMoIInAAn11o00r550.

*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted
```

I know stacking smashing means the buffer is being overflowed, but what concerns me more is that for some reason that I can't figure out, the num[] array is having its characters doubled in the final string. 
Instead of "CMMoII..." it should be "CMoI..."
Is this perhaps a side effect of the buffer overflow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sizeof(name)` and `sizeof(num)` is the size of a pointer, not of the array in the calling function. You can remove all `sizeof(char)`, because it is 1 by definition.

Comment: You need to use `strlen()` and not `sizeof()`.  For starters; there may be other problems too.

Comment: blah blah blah debugger blah blah blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The others have pointed out that arrays are "passed by reference". So you should not use `sizeof(name)` because that's just `sizeof(char*)`(correct me if i'm wrong; always 8), but rather `strlen(name)`.

```
char tmp[1] ={name[i]}; 
char tmp2[1] ={num[i]};
```

That might get you what you want, but its very redundant to create a char array for one element. Instead just create a char and pass a pointer to that char using the *&*:

```
char tmp = name[i];
printf("tmp: %s\n", &tmp);
```

The loop can be reduced to only two lines:

```
void printMessage(char* name, char* num){
   int len = strlen(name) + strlen(num);
   char* eticket = calloc(0,len +1); 
   int i,j,k;

   for(i=0, j=0, k=0; i<len;i++){
      if(j < strlen(name)) strncpy(&eticket[i++],&name[j++],1);
      if(k < strlen(num) ) strncpy(&eticket[i],&num[k++],1);
   }
   printf("Your name is %s and your flight number is %s.\nYour e-ticket is: %s.\n\n", name, num, eticket);
   free(eticket);
}
```

This does as you want it to, and is a lot cleaner. I skip the whole `strcat(..)` function, as its redundant. I use `strncpy(char * dst, const char * src, size_t len)` instead. 
How it works: 
 - *i* keeps the position in the *eticket*.
 - *j* keeps the position in the *name*.
 - *k* keeps the position in the *num*.

```
&eticket[i++]
```

This points to the *i'th* position in the *eticket* array(i is incremented afterward). That means that the whatever is copied into this, will start here.

```
&name[j++]
```

This is a pointer to the *j'th* element in the *name* array. This means that `strncpy` will start reading here, and copy ***1*** element into the *eticket* array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the extra explanation on how I can clean up my code. The & operator still throws me for a loop (heh).

Answer (score 2):

The function definition:

```
void printMessage(char name[], char num[]) { ... }
```

is same as

```
void printMessage(char* name, char* num) { ... }
```

In the function, `sizeof(name)` is equal to the size of a pointer. It does not evaluate to the length of the string.

You need to use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`. When you use `strlen`, you need to add an additional character for the terminating null character.

```
// eticket is now a VLA.
// Can't use ... = "";
char eticket[strlen(name)+strlen(num)+1];
```

You need to change other lines of code that use `sizeof` too.

Comment: Using `strlen` makes `eticket` to a VLA, which cannot be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

A quirk of the C language that is well-known to seasoned C programmers, but trips up new C coders to no end, is that arrays are "pass by reference". Generally speaking, an array name used in most expressions will decay to the address of its first element. Functions carry that to an extreme case, where the array syntax in the function parameter is actually an alias for the pointer type itself.

Thus, `name` and `num` in your function are actually pointers and not arrays, and therefore `sizeof(name)` is actually the same as `sizeof(char *)`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, when you pass arrays using a syntax like this:

> ```
> void printMessage(char name[], char num[])
> ```

the information on the *size* of the array is lost; what you are passing are basically *pointers* to the beginning of the array.

This means that an expression like `sizeof(name)/sizeof(char)` in this case is equivalent to:

```
sizeof(char *)/sizeof(char)
```

which is:

> (size of a pointer) / (size of a char)

On a 32-bit architecture, this typically evaluates to 4 (i.e. 4 bytes / 1 byte).

So, you may want to get the input string lengths at run-time, invoking `strlen()`, and allocate the output string array dynamically using `malloc()`.

e.g.

```
char * eticket = NULL;
...

/* 
 * Dynamically allocate memory for output string buffer.
 * Note: add +1 to consider the string's NUL-terminator.
 */
eticket = (char *)malloc(strlen(name) + strlen(num) + 1);

/* Check allocation failure */
if (eticket == NULL)
{
    /* Error */
    ...
}

/* Use eticket */
...

/* Don't forget to free memory! */
free(eticket);

/* Avoid dangling pointers */
eticket = NULL;
```